# In-use ram percentage doesnt match available memory

Tags: windows, memory

I've got an issue with my windows 10 OS and RAMs
images here are self describing enough!

[image: Memory Usage]

[image: user's total usage]

As you can see 3.6/16 = 22% not about 50%

[rammap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhTP0.png)

Comment: post picture of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) and loof in Taskmgr->perf->cpu for the number of handles. if you have over 100k handles you could [have Zombie Processes eating your RAM](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/zombie-processes-are-eating-your-memory/)

Comment: thanks. added RAMMap to the post. Total handles are about 79k

Comment: RAMMap data show 5GB of active used RAM. look for the zombie processes. so look at handle column in task manager

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only 'user' using system resources. The system itself uses resources to interact with hardware, run background processes and run certain UIs (such as the taskbar). This is known as system overhead, and there are a number of questions on SU about reducing its effects.

Comment: Of course there are other processes. but 4GB? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes complete sense. I currently have 83% usage even though the 'users' tab shows me using ~500MB.